# Terraforming a private PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, terraform

I got a PostgreSQL server running in AWS RDS on a private subnet. I have an SSH server running on a public subnet within the same VPC that I can tunnel through to get to the database:

```
$ ssh -Nnf -L 5432:my-db-host:5432 my-bastion-host -p 2222
$ kmp-vm ~/projects/delivery (feature/terraform_postgres) $ psql -h localhost -U root dbname
Password for user root: 
psql (14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), server 13.7)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

dbname=>
```

So far things are working as expected. I wish to use terraform to manage the schema and users and add a `terraform.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    postgresql = {
      source  = "cyrilgdn/postgresql"
      version = "~> 1.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "postgresql" {
  scheme          = "awspostgres"
  host            = "localhost"
  port            = 5432
  database        = "dbname"
  username        = "root"
  password        = "password"
  sslmode         = "disable"
  superuser       = false
  connect_timeout = 30
}

resource "postgresql_role" "admin" {
  name = "admin"
}
```

Trying to apply this results in the following error:

```
│ Error: error detecting capabilities: error PostgreSQL version: x509: certificate is valid for my-db-host, not localhost
│ 
│   with postgresql_role.admin,
│   on _terraform.tf line 22, in resource "postgresql_role" "admin":
│   22: resource "postgresql_role" "admin" {
│
```

How can I get around this?

**UPDATE**

This seems to be an `awspostgres` scheme thing (GoCloud). It seems to ignore the `sslmode` specified and it does not work with a socks proxy via `ALL_PROXY` either.

Switching scheme to `postgres` fixes the issue (unless `sslmode` is set to `verify-full` or alternatively via an socks proxy instead).

Given I do not really need the aws specific authentication methods this is an acceptable solution for my case here.